# Bounding box at wrong location to object

Tags: c#, xna, bounding-box

I am importing .fbx models (a simple cuboid), the model itself displays fine (and is repeated to make a wall) however the bounding box seems to be on the wrong location. Below is a screen shoot:

[image]

The yellow line is the bounding box for the grey cuboids.

The map walls are loaded from a map object that specifies where walls should be

```
for (int row = 0; row < map.Rows; row++){
    for (int col = 0; col < map.Columns; col++){
        if (map.Get(row, col) == 'w') walls.Add(new Wall(content.Load<Model>("models/wallnew"), new Vector3(col, 0, row)));
    }
}
```

and a wall is:

```
public class Wall : Entity {
    BoundingBox boundingBox;

    public Wall(Model model, Vector3 position) : base(model){
        this.translation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
        Vector3 from = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(0f), World);
        Vector3 to = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(1f), World);
        boundingBox = new BoundingBox(from, to);
    }

    public BoundingBox GetBoundingBox() {
        return boundingBox;
    }

    public override void Draw(bool textured, Matrix view, Matrix proj) {
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes) {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects) {
                effect.World = World * mesh.ParentBone.Transform;
                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = proj;
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
}
```

I cant for the life of me work out why the bounding box is being added wrong, if you need any more info let me know!